# Cannot start SQL Server 2022 on a system with TLS 1.3 only

Tags: ssl, sql-server, startup, windows-server-2022

From documentation it seems that SQL Server 2022 should support TLS 1.3:

> SQL Server 2022 (16.x) supports Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.3
> when TDS 8.0 is used. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/networking/tls-1-3?view=sql-server-ver16)

However, when I try to start a service on Windows Server 2022, where only TLS 1.3 is enabled (I have disabled TLS 1.2 and older protocols), the server will not start. I see the following errors in event log:

```
SQL Server could not spawn FRunCommunicationsManager thread. Check the SQL Server error log and the operating system error log for information about possible related problems.
Could not start the network library because of an internal error in the network library. To determine the cause, review the errors immediately preceding this one in the error log.
TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x139f, status code 0x1. Reason: Initialization failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation. 
TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x139f, status code 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support. The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation. 
The server was unable to initialize encryption because of a problem with a security library. The security library may be missing. Verify that security.dll exists on the system.
```

In earlier versions of Windows Server there was a similar problem with TLS 1.2 which was fixed with a patch. Is there anything similar for SQL Server 2022 and TLS 1.3? Or should TLS 1.2 be enabled anyway.

Comment: you need TLS 1.2 enabled..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly, to MS - TLS 1.2 is required for starting up SQL Server satellite services. They recommend keeping enabled TLS 1.2 on your server.
Please pay attention to this article:
[TLS 1.3 support - SQL Server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/networking/tls-1-3?view=sql-server-ver16)

Here is the screenshot:

[image: TLS 1.3 Recommendations]